# Creating Instance of CallbackManager.Factory.create();

Tags: android

when i write this code why the color of mFacebookCallbackManager changes to red saying cannot resolve symbol mFacebookCallbackManager

```
public class signin extends AppCompatActivity  {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);

 }

 }
```

Manifest File

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

Kindly help me out to solve the problem

Comment: You must declare variable of `mFacebookCallbackManager` in declaration part.

Comment: Thanks Man @piyush

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the variable `mFacebookCallbackManager`.